# Creating landslide susceptibility map using logistic regression and ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geostatistical-analyst, regression

My project is to build a landslide susceptibility map using logistics regression. I have generated the following maps so far:

slope map, hill shade, curvature, elevation, road buffers, river buffers of 100 - 500m , Aspect, land use land cover, ndvi.

All of these maps after production do not have attribute tables. please, I need a detailed explanation on how to use some of this data produced to produce a susceptibility map using logistic regression.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Comment: A good starting place would be to conduct a search in the academic literature on the topic. A quick Google Scholar search revealed 928 journal articles including: Bai et al. (2010) GIS-based logistic regression for landslide susceptibility mapping of the Zhongxian segment in the Three Gorges area, China, Geomorphology, 115(1–2), 23–31. I suspect you'll ultimately need to take a sample of the data generated in the GIS and use a statistical language like R for the actual logistic regression but read the methods of several of the academic papers and see how they did it.

Comment: Logit regression is only possible in ArcGIS by incorporating R.  You can download a vector based script tool here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a5736544d97a4544aa47d06baf910f6d.  More details on this subject here:  https://geonet.esri.com/thread/41562

Comment: Also note that researchers in this field are also increasingly using machine learning alternatives to regression, including random forest classification and support vector machines, which are also possible to carry out using R.

Comment: thanks for the promp awnser but I need an indept explanation cause I am a nivice and most of the image analysis performed are as a result of the helpful tutorials from youutube

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Unfortunately, as it stands I think your question is too broad for our format because your request for an in depth explanation of a topic that the comments so far indicate is a large one.  From the [Help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), I think it verges on "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much".  You may find that a quick review of the [GIS SE Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) is also helpful to familiarize yourself with some of the protocols used here.

Comment: Thanks but I seriously need help as this is my final year project.... pleasssssss!!!